# ggplot2 + Date structure using scale X

Tags: r, ggplot2

I really need help here because I am way beyond lost.

I am trying to create a line chart showing several teams' performance over a year. I divided the year into quarters: 1/1/2012, 4/1/12. 8/1/12. 12/1/12 and loaded the csv data frame into R.

```
     Month               Team Position
1   1/1/12       South Africa       56
2   1/1/12             Angola       85
3   1/1/12            Morocco       61
4   1/1/12 Cape Verde Islands       58
5   4/1/12       South Africa       71
6   4/1/12             Angola       78
7   4/1/12            Morocco       62
8   4/1/12 Cape Verde Islands       76
9   8/1/12       South Africa       67
10  8/1/12             Angola       85
11  8/1/12            Morocco       68
12  8/1/12 Cape Verde Islands       78
13 12/1/12       South Africa       87
14 12/1/12             Angola       84
15 12/1/12            Morocco       72
16 12/1/12 Cape Verde Islands       69
```

When I try using ggplot2 to generate the graph the fourth quarter 12/1/12 inexplicably moves to the second spot.

```
ggplot(groupA, aes(x=Month, y=Position, colour=Team, group=Team)) + geom_line()
```

I then put this plot into a variable GA in order to try to use scale_x to format the date:

```
GA + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%d"))
```

But I keep getting this Error:

```
Error in structure(list(call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  :
```

could not find function "date_format"

And if I run this code:

```
GA + scale_x_date()
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

I am using a Mac OS X running R 2.15.2

Please help.

Comment: Sorry. How do I do that?

Comment: @Syia and as a polite action you can upvote , specially when you accept the solution...This will encourage people to help you next time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because, `df$Month`, (assuming your `data.frame` is `df`), which is a `factor` has its levels in this order.

```
> levels(df$Month)
# [1] "1/1/12"  "12/1/12" "4/1/12"  "8/1/12"
```

The solution is to re-order the levels of your factor.

```
df$Month <- factor(df$Month, levels=df$Month[!duplicated(df$Month)])
> levels(df$Month)
# [1] "1/1/12"  "4/1/12"  "8/1/12"  "12/1/12"
```

[image: ggplot2_factor_levels]

**Edit:** Alternate solution using `strptime`

```
# You could convert Month first:
 df$Month <- strptime(df$Month, '%m/%d/%y')
```

Then your code should work. Check the plot below:

[image: ggplot2_strptime_solution]

Comment: @Arun How do you succed to read his data..when I tried I had some problem...using read.table(text='..')