# change date to the last day of the month

Tags: r

I've tried to change the character variable into a variable of class Date, then changed it to the last day of the month.

```
data %>% mutate("Month"= as.Date(paste(Month,"-01",sep=""))) -> data
data$Month <- paste(format(data$Month, format="%Y-%m"),"-", days_in_month(data$Month), sep="")
```

This works when run through the console but when I try to knit to pdf I get

> Error in days_in_month(data$Month) :
> could not find function "days_in_month"
> Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> paste
> In addition: Warning message:
> In has_crop_tools() :
> Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: ghostcript
> -> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
> Execution halted

I want to keep as.Date and days_in_month() but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and is it possible to join the second line of code to the first line?

Comment: Looks like you didn't call the `library` in your Rmarkdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, lubridate)

data <- tribble( ~ id, ~ Month,
                 1, "2020-04",
                 2, "2020-05",
                 3, "2020-12")
data %>%
  mutate(Month = ymd(paste0(Month, "-01")),
         Month = Month + days(days_in_month(Month) - 1))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      id Month     
#>   <dbl> <date>    
#> 1     1 2020-04-30
#> 2     2 2020-05-31
#> 3     3 2020-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
library(lubridate)
```

in some chunk before that command. It should work.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815365/error-invalid-input-date-trans-works-with-objects-of-class-date-only/41876606 for that